# Java 8 Lambda - Pivot Data Table by Index in Sequential Read

Tags: java

I have a Data Table, `List<APIQueue>`, which comes back as groups of 6-tuples stored as PARAM_KEY/VALUE sequentially. I need to create a `List<APIBean>` which separates these into row beans.

[image]

```
public class APIQueue extends {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer transactionId;
    private String parameterKey;
    private String parameterValue;  
    // + Getters/setters...

}
```

Target Bean

```
public class APIBean {

    public String applId;
    public String transactionType;
    public String phsOrgCode;
    public String roleTypeCode;
    public String personId;
    public String versionId;

    public APIBean(String applId, String transactionType, String phsOrgCode, String roleTypeCode, String personId,
            String versionId) {
        this.applId = applId;
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
        this.phsOrgCode = phsOrgCode;
        this.roleTypeCode = roleTypeCode;
        this.personId = personId;
        this.versionId = versionId;
    }
    // + Getters/Setters
```

I need to separate by Row Index. It's guaranteed that APPLID is #1, TRANSACTIONTYPE #2, etc.

I wonder if I should just do a sequential `while`-loop with `unitCount += 5` and maybe that would be easier to populate the bean list. But if Lambdas are a better solution I can use that.

Expected Result `List<APIBean>` from the sequential read:

```
9643874  |  U  |  CA  |  GS  |  7734701  | M
9645606  |  U  |  CA  |  GS  |  7734701  | M
```

How would this be implemented? I'm only familiar with the following Constructor Mapping, which doesn't apply here.

```
    List<APIQueue> apiQueueData = getAPIQueueData();

    // Can't use that here
    List<APIBean> apiBeans = apiQueueData.stream().map(obj -> new APIBean(obj.getField1(), obj.getField2(), ...));
```

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: e.g. Bean 1: `APPLID=9643874, TRANSACTIONTYPE=U, PHSORGCODE=CA, ROLETYPECODE=GS, PERSONID=7734701, VERSIONID=M`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 streams are mainly designed to process elements independently, but you're using data from 6 consecutive elements to create one output element. You'd need to do something like this to break it into sublists and process those:

```
List<APIBean> apiBeans = IntStream.range(0, apiQueueData.size() / 6)
        .mapToObj(i -> apiQueueData.subList(i * 6, (i + 1) * 6))
        .map(data -> {
            String applId = data.get(0).getParameterValue();
            String transactionType = data.get(1).getParameterValue();
            String phsOrgCode = data.get(2).getParameterValue();
            String roleTypeCode = data.get(3).getParameterValue();
            String personId = data.get(4).getParameterValue();
            String versionId = data.get(5).getParameterValue();
            return new APIBean(applId, transactionType, phsOrgCode, roleTypeCode, personId, versionId);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For this problem, I would suggest using an iterator instead:

```
List<APIBean> apiBeans = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<APIQueue> i = apiQueueData.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    String applId = i.next().getParameterValue();
    String transactionType = i.next().getParameterValue();
    String phsOrgCode = i.next().getParameterValue();
    String roleTypeCode = i.next().getParameterValue();
    String personId = i.next().getParameterValue();
    String versionId = i.next().getParameterValue();
    apiBeans.add(new APIBean(applId, transactionType, phsOrgCode, roleTypeCode, personId, versionId));
}
```